# PCM to decibel conversion in ESP-IDF using PDM microphone

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, dsp, mems-microphone, esp-idf

I am using PDM microphone with ESP32-Wroom-32. By using ESP-IDF i2s_pdm_rx example. I was able to get PCM data steam in an array buffer from these `int16_t` values. How can I measure sound pressure?

I read on ESP-IDF API guides that this data in converted by ESP32 from PDM to PCM. I am not sure about that either if remember correctly someone point out only ESP32-S3 can convert PDM to PCM at peripheral stage.

I am new to audio processing don’t know much about DSP.

```cpp
int16_t *r_buf = (int16_t *)calloc(1, EXAMPLE_BUFF_SIZE);

i2s_channel_read(rx_chan, r_buf, EXAMPLE_BUFF_SIZE, &r_bytes, 1000);
```

`r_buf` will get PCM data. How can I convert it to decibels sound measurement?

I tried to measure root mean square of this PCM signal than take log but most of the values results in `nan` or `-inf`.

Answer (score 2):

"dB" is always relative to a reference, and 0 dB is equal to the reference.

For digital data, "dBFS" (decibel full scale) use the largest possible digital values as the reference, so for signed 16-bit values, 0 dBFS is ±32767.

For dBSPL (decibel sound pressure level) you need to know the conversion factors of your microphone, preamplifier, ADC, and all the other components in the signal chain.

Comment: i am using mems digital microphone IM73D122 by Infineon Technologies there no other component in between pdm is directly connected to esp32-wroom-32 i2s interface.

Comment: @MoazAzam That didn't answer the question. dB by itself means very little. What are you after? dBFS? dBSPL? Something else?

Comment: @winny I am trying to measure dBSPL?

Comment: @MoazAzam Please edit your question to state so. You'll need the sensitivity of your microphone in order to do the calculation.

Comment: Microphone sensitivity is 1kHz, 94dBSPL, all operating modes = -26 dBFS @winny can you please help me with calculations i am really struck here.

Comment: @MoazAzam Good, then 0 dBFS is 94+26=120 dBSPL unweighted. Calculate your RMS value scaled from 0 dBFS, take log10 of that, and add 120 to get dBSPL.

Comment: again @winny sorry for asking soo much. how can i calculate the rms value scaled from 0 dBFS. everyone has use different calculation. can you please mention steps to calculate rms from int16_t array. thanks again

Comment: @MoazAzam What did your own search and attempts reveal? You won't learn anything if I write the code for you.

Comment: Currently i am doing sum += pcm[i]*pcm[i] for 1024 samples than i and dividing sum by 1024 than taking square root than log10 of rms and adding 120 but values range from 120 to 500 when i speak to test my code. i have downloaded an app in my phone that show values from 30 to 90 when i speak to test both app and code together.

Comment: @winny i dont know where i am going wrong or what step i am missing

Answer (score 0):

If the logarithm of your RMS is -inf, the RMS was 0. So, make sure you're really averaging the right things, correctly.

Also, don't average, just sum; division is expensive, and integer division might be the reason you're getting zeros where you shouldn't. You're familiar with logarithm arithmetic, so I only need to remind you that division of what you take the logarithm of is just the same as subtracting the logarithm of the divisor afterwards.

In general: develop your signal processing algorithms in C that you can test on your PC with synthetic data before testing it with ADC data. Much easier to find such bugs that way!

Comment: i am not sure in what format esp32 read data from i2s i tried adding all array element than calculate rms and decibel but value become constant that way not change at all

Comment: One more reason to separate developing  your math from your data conversion. It makes no sense to try and understand where your math goes wrong when you don't even understand what your data is. Figure that out first.